# Updating a table based on foreign key condition from a different table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I want to UPDATE a set of rows in one table based on the condition that there are more than 2 movie showings in a theater. I tried to use the typicall

`UPDATE table SET changedData WHERE condition`

Example:
Table 1- theater: theaterID - Primary Key, theaterName ,City,Capacity

Table 2- movies: actorID - foreign key, theaterID-foreign key,ConcertDate- primary key

If the 'TheaterID' in the 'movies' table occured more than once then change the 'Capacity' in the 'Theater' table to 40000.

My attempt:

```
UPDATE Theater set capacity = 40000 WHERE SELECT COUNT(theaterid)=2 FROM 
movies;
```

But I keep getting errors

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Comment: You have not joined Movies with Theater - `update theater set capacity=40000 where 2` is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  UPDATE  Theater 
  set capacity = 40000 
  WHERE theaterID  IN (select theaterID 
               FROM movies GROUP BY theaterID 
               HAVING COUNT(theaterID )>2)
```

Comment: That did the trick! So I just need to create a link between the two tables using GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Theater 
set capacity = 40000 
WHERE theaterID IN 
(SELECT theaterID 
 FROM movies
 GROUP BY theaterID 
 HAVING COUNT(*)=2)